# SQL Query to get data without missing out order number

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Imagine I have 100 over data and I'm selecting top 10 records based on group of order number but the problem here is my 10th record falls as ORDER103. If I would select that record, the rest two data which belongs to ORDER103 will be ignored. How do I group select the record from ORDER101 to ORDER102 so that I can able to fetch ORDER103 on the next select query?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  "Imagine I have 100 over data..." What does that mean?  Please update your question to include sample data in text format (not an image) and also add your desired results in text format.  You should also include what code you have tried so far.

Comment: What should happen if `ORDER101` alone has more than 10 tracking numbers?

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say that you want all rows containing the top 10 tracking number values?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT TOP (10) WITH TIES
       tracking_number
     , order_number
FROM   your_table
ORDER
    BY order_number
;
```

> `WITH TIES`
>
> Returns two or more rows that tie for last place in the limited results set. You must use this argument with the ORDER BY clause. WITH TIES might cause more rows to be returned than the value specified in expression. For example, if expression is set to 5 but two additional rows match the values of the ORDER BY columns in row 5, the result set will contain seven rows.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments